# Ruby regex: split string with match beginning with either a newline or the start of the string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, pattern-matching

Here's my regular expression that I have for this. I'm in Ruby, which — if I'm not mistaken — uses POSIX regular expressions.

```
regex = /(?:\n^)(\*[\w+ ?]+\*)\n/
```

Here's my goal: I want to split a string with a regex that is `*delimited by asterisks*`, including those asterisks. *However*: I only want to split by the match if it is prefaced with a newline character (`\n`), or it's the start of the whole string. This is the string I'm working with.

```
"*Friday*\nDo not *break here*\n*But break here*\nBut again, not this"
```

My regular expression is not splitting properly at the `*Friday*` match, but it *is* splitting at the `*But break here*` match (it's also throwing in a `here` split). My issue is somewhere in the first group, I think: `(?:\n^)` — I know it's wrong, and I'm not entirely sure of the correct way to write it. Can someone shed some light? Here's my complete code.

```
regex = /(?:\n^)(\*[\w+ ?]+\*)\n/
str = "*Friday*\nDo not *break here*\n*But break here*\nBut again, not this"
str.split(regex)
```

Which results in this:

```
>>> ["*Friday*\nDo not *break here*", "*But break here*", "But again, not this"]
```

I want it to be this:

```
>>> ["*Friday*", "Do not *break here*", "*But break here*", "But again, not this"]
```

**Edit #1**: I've updated my regex and result. (2011/10/18 16:26 CST)
**Edit #2**: I've updated both again. (16:32 CST)

Comment: Is your string like this? Or the actual \n is a different line?

Comment: The line breaks are indeed in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just add a '\n' to the front of each string. That simplifies the processing quite a bit:

```
regex = /(?:\n)(\*[\w+ ?]+\*)\n/
str = "*Friday*\nDo not *break here*\n*But break here*\nBut again, not this"

res = ("\n"+str).split(regex)
res.shift if res[0] == ""
res
=> [ "*Friday*", "Do not *break here*", 
     "*But break here*", "But again, not this"]
```

We have to watch for the initial extra match but it's not too bad. I suspect someone can shorten this a bit.

Comment: I gotta say, this one works the best. There's a blank line at the beginning of the array, but you account for that, too (I've got an `Array` extension method that deletes any blank or nil entries, which is what I'll use). Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Groups 1 & 2 of the regex below :

```
(?:\A|\\n)(\*.*?\*)|(?:\A|\\n)(.*?)(?=\\n|\Z)
```

Will give you your desired output. I am no ruby expert so you will have to create the list yourself :)

Comment: I was only able to get this regex to work after removing the escapings on the `\n`'s. I went with @Paul Rubel's solution as it's a little less obfuscated.

Comment: @BenjaminKreeger It's ok. As I said I don't know ruby :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split at newlines? From your example, it looks that's what you're really trying to do.

```
str.split("\n")
```